# Accessing device console in VM

Tags: console, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a windows OS and I'm running Ubuntu on virtualbox. I want to access the HP switch on Ubuntu VM via console. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Virtual box of the respective VM being used, check **Settings -> Serial Ports** and enable serial port.
Also mention the Port Number which is being used, e.g., COM1.